# Help parsing つまんないないんだよ

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics, i-adjectives

I have a question about the grammar (assuming it is grammatical and not figurative) in the following line from the song ときめきポポロン from the anime ご注文はうさぎですか？.

> つまんないないんだよ

I think the meaning is pretty clear (we won't be bored) but I'm curious about the seemingly extra ない.  Would つまらないんだよ have the exact same meaning? Is it common to add ない to いadjectives for emphasis?

Comment: Uhh. Isn't it like つまらない+ない= not つまらない?

Comment: つまらない means "boring"..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ない can be repeated many times for emphasis (ie. ないないないない… ≒ No, no, no, no, no...) even in ordinary conversations, and it just means **"absolutely no/impossible"** regardless of whether the number is even or odd.

つまんないない is certainly ungrammatical in everyday writings, but since it's a song, I think this just means つまんない (boring), emphasized in a peculiar way only found in lyrics.

With [this full-text lyrics search service](http://www.uta-net.com/) I could easily find similar examples of repeated ない:

- [Crazy Dancer](http://www.uta-net.com/song/203374/) by 夜の本気ダンス

  > **足りないないない**夜明かしでも
  >   **せつないないない**ごまかしてんだ

  ([video](https://youtu.be/XnkPpSKv20c?t=1m7s))
- [オールカテゴライズ](http://www.uta-net.com/song/197232/) by 焚吐

  > 絶望感に苛まれても　この手で救い**たいたいたい**　だから
  >   (snip)
  >   そんな世界を想像したけど　だめだめ　**ありえないないない**　だけど

  ([video](https://youtu.be/YQleDJAZtZo?t=58s) for the たいたいたい part)
- [Start it right away](http://www.uta-net.com/song/129264/) by ヒャダイン

  > **全く関係ないないないないない**とか　言い散らかして

  ([video](https://youtu.be/K8lBBV9ISDw?t=2m))

Well, there are only two ない's in ときめきポポロン, but [after actually listening to the song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qk9pucVX2nk), I think it's safe to say this (つまん)ないない is used in the same way as the above.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, what "つまんないないんだよ" means is not clear, mainly because... it's ungrammatical. If you want to put "つまんない(boring)" into a negative by adding ない, the correct way is to inflect the first "ない", um, accordingly, so that you get "つまんな**く**ない(not boring)".

Assuming this goof is all intentional, which it most likely is, just the songwriter playing around with words, then what do they intend it to mean?

I think it's either that they really meant negative, but chose to ignore the rules, because they can (well it's a song), or that they put the extra ない without adding any semantic value, just for the hell of it (well it's an anime song).

So which one is it? -- I really don't know. In cases like this, looking at the context will surely help? So here it is:

> ハートもふもふ 暖かい気持ちおすそわけしたい つまんないないよ あれこれそれもしよう

... which leaves me even more mystified.

This is as close to the bottom of the question as I could get. Sorry for the indefinite answer. My initial gut feeling said it was "for the hell of it", if it's any redemption.

==EDIT==

After turning the quote over in my mind a little more, and actually watching the video for the song, I'm much more inclined to think the "つまんないない" is just a "つまんない" with double ない, the extra one added for artistic reason, not negation. So "つまんないないよ あれこれそれもしよう", I think, is saying "It's so boring! (So) let's do this and that and such and such!"